# Execution of loop till the variable is zero in Java

Tags: java

I need to subtract a value, and each line it traverses the for takes the subtraction value of the last one until that value reaches zero.

My code :

```
float total = Float.parseFloat(this.tfInputValue.getText());
int lines = tbAccountsReceiveCustomer.getRowCount(); 

for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    float value = (float) tbAccountsReceiveCustomer.getValueAt(i, 5);
    total -= value; 

    System.out.println("Total entry : " + total);
}
```

**Example :**

If the users enter the `total` variable as 78, and the user enter the values 23 and 54 in the variable `value`, he will make the follow :

> 78 - 23 = 55
>
> 55 - 54 = 1

But I can't make the variable `total` reaches zero, because he only takes the first final value and don't continue to subtract.

How can I make this work ?

Comment: Why can\t the user enter 55 instead of 54 to reach zero?

Comment: Actually, I have to get the last result gave in the subtraction and next time use it to subtract the other number.

Comment: If you need one more iteration, just use `for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use an static variable. This is part of a bigger system?

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: I don't believe that, look that I'm proposing a solution Miguel.